# How to use airflow in a virtual environment, with the operators running outside of a virtual env?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, virtualenv, airflow

I have been using airflow for the past few weeks, having installed it, its dependencies and all the requirements of the dags I need to run inside of a py 2.7 virtual env. I would like to be able to create a python 3 virtual environment, install only airflow and its dependencies inside, and then create dags with python operators that would use the python 2.7 distribution and all its libraries on my machine.

One way that I have been thinking to do this is to only use bash operators where I specify the python version to use every time, but this doesn't seem very clean, is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738173/how-to-run-airflow-pythonoperator-in-a-virtual-environment) is about running DAGs in their dedicated virtual environment using a workaround but does not answer your question.

Regarding installing AirFlow in its own dedicated virtual environment you can have a look at [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and [pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56890937/how-to-use-apache-airflow-in-a-virtual-environment) may help too.